# Windows Phone Power Tool (Pre WP-8) Fails To Load Folder Content

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

My environment : Win7, VS2010 Pro, Windows Phone Emulator 10.1.40219.390, HTC T8788, Windows Phone Power Tool v1.6.

I need to Get multiple files (they are <3kb json files) to my dev box from a folder on my emulator/device. I had been happily doing this with Isolated Explorer command tool and/or Windows Phone Power Tool till the number of files was very limited. As soon as the number of files increased in the folder both the tools mentioned above failed to open the folder from device. The application on device and emulator is handling large number of files as expected (tested with 4000+ files). Following are my findings regarding the issue with WPPT (and IS explorer): if a folder contains more than 1024 files, WPPT does not load the folder. The physical size of individual file in the folder does not matter. The issue can be reproduced with same effect on emulator and device. On further investigation I found that WPPT breaks at a call to Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.RemoteIsolatedStorageFile.GetDirectoryListing() which just says - "Unspecified error" with no details. It seems the said API method is now obsolete and i could not find any substantial information on MSDN about it or the issue

Did somebody else also encounter this problem? Is there some way I can pull large number of files (4000+) to my dev box from IS folder on device/emulator (please note, i can only work with the environment mentioned above, so Win8 or WP8 emulator are out of question)?

Regards.

Comment: Can you put combine the files (append to existing) rather than create a new one?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot I cannot make any changes to how the data is created by the application. I have access to the data generated by the app.